# Devise Not Storing User Session Info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, devise, mongoid

I'm building an app with **Rails 4.1.4**, **Mongoid 4.0.0** and **Devise 3.3.0** (*Warden 1.2.3*) for authentication.

Everything about authentication with **Devise** is working well (*sign up*, *sign in*, *confirmation*, *password recovery*, etc.). The issue I'm having is that when I sign in, although it says that sign in was successful, and in the database the *sign_in_count* increases and *last_sign_in_at* updates, the user session is not being stored in the cookies, namely the helpers user_signed_in?, user_session, current_user, etc. are not working.

I actually have two distinct models that work with authentication, one named Customer and one named Admin. So my helpers are **customer_*** or ***_customer**, and **admin_*** or ***_admin** respectively. None of them working.

These are my models...

**customer.rb**

```
class Customer
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, 
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  # Database authenticatable
  field :email,              type: String
  field :encrypted_password, type: String

  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_presence_of :encrypted_password

  # Recoverable
  field :reset_password_token,   type: String
  field :reset_password_sent_at, type: Time

  # Rememberable
  field :remember_created_at, type: Time

  # Trackable
  field :sign_in_count,      type: Integer, default: 0
  field :current_sign_in_at, type: Time
  field :last_sign_in_at,    type: Time
  field :current_sign_in_ip, type: String
  field :last_sign_in_ip,    type: String

  # Confirmable
  field :confirmation_token,   type: String
  field :confirmed_at,         type: Time
  field :confirmation_sent_at, type: Time
  field :unconfirmed_email,    type: String # Only if using reconfirmable

  # Lockable
  # field :failed_attempts, :type => Integer, :default => 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
  # field :unlock_token,    :type => String # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
  # field :locked_at,       :type => Time

  # Token authenticatable
  # field :authentication_token, :type => String

  # Run 'rake db:mongoid:create_indexes' to create indexes
  index({ email: 1 }, { unique: true, background: true })

  # Extra data.
  field :first_name, type: String
  field :last_name, type: String
  validates_presence_of :first_name
  validates_presence_of :last_name

  # Devise serializing problem fix.
  class << self
    def serialize_from_session(key,salt)
      record = to_adapter.get(key[0].to_param)
      record if record && record.authenticatable_salt == salt
    end
  end
end
```

**admin.rb**

```
class Admin
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  devise :database_authenticatable, :timeoutable, :lockable

  # Database authenticatable
  field :email,              type: String
  field :encrypted_password, type: String

  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_presence_of :encrypted_password

  # Lockable
  field :failed_attempts, type: Integer, default: 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
  field :unlock_token,    type: String # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
  field :locked_at,       type: Time

  # Run 'rake db:mongoid:create_indexes' to create indexes
  index({ email: 1 }, { unique: true, background: true })

  # Extra data.
  field :is_admin,  type: Boolean, default: false
  field :is_editor, type: Boolean, default: true

  # Devise serializing problem fix.
  class << self
    def serialize_from_session(key,salt)
      record = to_adapter.get(key[0].to_param)
      record if record && record.authenticatable_salt == salt
    end
  end
end
```

And my initializer just in case...

**devise.rb**

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  # The secret key used by Devise. Devise uses this key to generate
  # random tokens. Changing this key will render invalid all existing
  # confirmation, reset password and unlock tokens in the database.
  config.secret_key = <secret_key>

  # ==> Mailer Configuration
  # Configure the e-mail address which will be shown in Devise::Mailer,
  # note that it will be overwritten if you use your own mailer class
  # with default "from" parameter.
  config.mailer_sender = <mailer_sender>

  # Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
  # config.mailer = 'Devise::Mailer'

  # ==> ORM configuration
  # Load and configure the ORM. Supports :active_record (default) and
  # :mongoid (bson_ext recommended) by default. Other ORMs may be
  # available as additional gems.
  require 'devise/orm/mongoid'

  # ==> Configuration for any authentication mechanism
  # Configure which keys are used when authenticating a user. The default is
  # just :email. You can configure it to use [:username, :subdomain], so for
  # authenticating a user, both parameters are required. Remember that those
  # parameters are used only when authenticating and not when retrieving from
  # session. If you need permissions, you should implement that in a before filter.
  # You can also supply a hash where the value is a boolean determining whether
  # or not authentication should be aborted when the value is not present.
  # config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]

  # Configure parameters from the request object used for authentication. Each entry
  # given should be a request method and it will automatically be passed to the
  # find_for_authentication method and considered in your model lookup. For instance,
  # if you set :request_keys to [:subdomain], :subdomain will be used on authentication.
  # The same considerations mentioned for authentication_keys also apply to request_keys.
  # config.request_keys = []

  # Configure which authentication keys should be case-insensitive.
  # These keys will be downcased upon creating or modifying a user and when used
  # to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]

  # Configure which authentication keys should have whitespace stripped.
  # These keys will have whitespace before and after removed upon creating or
  # modifying a user and when used to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]

  # Tell if authentication through request.params is enabled. True by default.
  # It can be set to an array that will enable params authentication only for the
  # given strategies, for example, `config.params_authenticatable = [:database]` will
  # enable it only for database (email + password) authentication.
  config.params_authenticatable = [:database]

  # Tell if authentication through HTTP Auth is enabled. False by default.
  # It can be set to an array that will enable http authentication only for the
  # given strategies, for example, `config.http_authenticatable = [:database]` will
  # enable it only for database authentication. The supported strategies are:
  # :database      = Support basic authentication with authentication key + password
  # config.http_authenticatable = false

  # If http headers should be returned for AJAX requests. True by default.
  # config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = true

  # The realm used in Http Basic Authentication. 'Application' by default.
  # config.http_authentication_realm = 'Application'

  # It will change confirmation, password recovery and other workflows
  # to behave the same regardless if the e-mail provided was right or wrong.
  # Does not affect registerable.
  config.paranoid = true

  # By default Devise will store the user in session. You can skip storage for
  # particular strategies by setting this option.
  # Notice that if you are skipping storage for all authentication paths, you
  # may want to disable generating routes to Devise's sessions controller by
  # passing skip: :sessions to `devise_for` in your config/routes.rb
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]

  # By default, Devise cleans up the CSRF token on authentication to
  # avoid CSRF token fixation attacks. This means that, when using AJAX
  # requests for sign in and sign up, you need to get a new CSRF token
  # from the server. You can disable this option at your own risk.
  # config.clean_up_csrf_token_on_authentication = true

  # ==> Configuration for :database_authenticatable
  # For bcrypt, this is the cost for hashing the password and defaults to 10. If
  # using other encryptors, it sets how many times you want the password re-encrypted.
  #
  # Limiting the stretches to just one in testing will increase the performance of
  # your test suite dramatically. However, it is STRONGLY RECOMMENDED to not use
  # a value less than 10 in other environments. Note that, for bcrypt (the default
  # encryptor), the cost increases exponentially with the number of stretches (e.g.
  # a value of 20 is already extremely slow: approx. 60 seconds for 1 calculation).
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10

  # Setup a pepper to generate the encrypted password.
  config.pepper = <pepper>

  # ==> Configuration for :confirmable
  # A period that the user is allowed to access the website even without
  # confirming their account. For instance, if set to 2.days, the user will be
  # able to access the website for two days without confirming their account,
  # access will be blocked just in the third day. Default is 0.days, meaning
  # the user cannot access the website without confirming their account.
  # config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 2.days

  # A period that the user is allowed to confirm their account before their
  # token becomes invalid. For example, if set to 3.days, the user can confirm
  # their account within 3 days after the mail was sent, but on the fourth day
  # their account can't be confirmed with the token any more.
  # Default is nil, meaning there is no restriction on how long a user can take
  # before confirming their account.
  # config.confirm_within = 3.days

  # If true, requires any email changes to be confirmed (exactly the same way as
  # initial account confirmation) to be applied. Requires additional unconfirmed_email
  # db field (see migrations). Until confirmed, new email is stored in
  # unconfirmed_email column, and copied to email column on successful confirmation.
  config.reconfirmable = true

  # Defines which key will be used when confirming an account
  config.confirmation_keys = [ :email ]

  # ==> Configuration for :rememberable
  # The time the user will be remembered without asking for credentials again.
  config.remember_for = 2.weeks

  # If true, extends the user's remember period when remembered via cookie.
  # config.extend_remember_period = false

  # Options to be passed to the created cookie. For instance, you can set
  # secure: true in order to force SSL only cookies.
  config.rememberable_options = { secure: true }

  # ==> Configuration for :validatable
  # Range for password length.
  config.password_length = 8..128

  # Email regex used to validate email formats. It simply asserts that
  # one (and only one) @ exists in the given string. This is mainly
  # to give user feedback and not to assert the e-mail validity.
  config.email_regexp = /\A[^@]+@[^@]+\z/

  # ==> Configuration for :timeoutable
  # The time you want to timeout the user session without activity. After this
  # time the user will be asked for credentials again. Default is 30 minutes.
  config.timeout_in = 30.minutes

  # If true, expires auth token on session timeout.
  # config.expire_auth_token_on_timeout = false

  # ==> Configuration for :lockable
  # Defines which strategy will be used to lock an account.
  # :failed_attempts = Locks an account after a number of failed attempts to sign in.
  # :none            = No lock strategy. You should handle locking by yourself.
  config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts

  # Defines which key will be used when locking and unlocking an account
  config.unlock_keys = [ :email ]

  # Defines which strategy will be used to unlock an account.
  # :email = Sends an unlock link to the user email
  # :time  = Re-enables login after a certain amount of time (see :unlock_in below)
  # :both  = Enables both strategies
  # :none  = No unlock strategy. You should handle unlocking by yourself.
  config.unlock_strategy = :both

  # Number of authentication tries before locking an account if lock_strategy
  # is failed attempts.
  config.maximum_attempts = 20

  # Time interval to unlock the account if :time is enabled as unlock_strategy.
  config.unlock_in = 1.hour

  # Warn on the last attempt before the account is locked.
  config.last_attempt_warning = true

  # ==> Configuration for :recoverable
  #
  # Defines which key will be used when recovering the password for an account
  config.reset_password_keys = [ :email ]

  # Time interval you can reset your password with a reset password key.
  # Don't put a too small interval or your users won't have the time to
  # change their passwords.
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours

  # ==> Configuration for :encryptable
  # Allow you to use another encryption algorithm besides bcrypt (default). You can use
  # :sha1, :sha512 or encryptors from others authentication tools as :clearance_sha1,
  # :authlogic_sha512 (then you should set stretches above to 20 for default behavior)
  # and :restful_authentication_sha1 (then you should set stretches to 10, and copy
  # REST_AUTH_SITE_KEY to pepper).
  #
  # Require the `devise-encryptable` gem when using anything other than bcrypt
  # config.encryptor = :sha512

  # ==> Scopes configuration
  # Turn scoped views on. Before rendering "sessions/new", it will first check for
  # "users/sessions/new". It's turned off by default because it's slower if you
  # are using only default views.
  config.scoped_views = true

  # Configure the default scope given to Warden. By default it's the first
  # devise role declared in your routes (usually :user).
  # config.default_scope = :user

  # Set this configuration to false if you want /users/sign_out to sign out
  # only the current scope. By default, Devise signs out all scopes.
  # config.sign_out_all_scopes = true

  # ==> Navigation configuration
  # Lists the formats that should be treated as navigational. Formats like
  # :html, should redirect to the sign in page when the user does not have
  # access, but formats like :xml or :json, should return 401.
  #
  # If you have any extra navigational formats, like :iphone or :mobile, you
  # should add them to the navigational formats lists.
  #
  # The "*/*" below is required to match Internet Explorer requests.
  config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html]

  # The default HTTP method used to sign out a resource. Default is :delete.
  config.sign_out_via = :delete

  # ==> OmniAuth
  # Add a new OmniAuth provider. Check the wiki for more information on setting
  # up on your models and hooks.
  # config.omniauth :github, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET', scope: 'user,public_repo'

  # ==> Warden configuration
  # If you want to use other strategies, that are not supported by Devise, or
  # change the failure app, you can configure them inside the config.warden block.
  #
  # config.warden do |manager|
  #   manager.intercept_401 = false
  #   manager.default_strategies(scope: :user).unshift :some_external_strategy
  # end

  # ==> Mountable engine configurations
  # When using Devise inside an engine, let's call it `MyEngine`, and this engine
  # is mountable, there are some extra configurations to be taken into account.
  # The following options are available, assuming the engine is mounted as:
  #
  #     mount MyEngine, at: '/my_engine'
  #
  # The router that invoked `devise_for`, in the example above, would be:
  # config.router_name = :my_engine
  #
  # When using omniauth, Devise cannot automatically set Omniauth path,
  # so you need to do it manually. For the users scope, it would be:
  # config.omniauth_path_prefix = '/my_engine/users/auth'
end
```

Any hint to fix this problem?. Would really appreciate it!. Best,

**UPDATE!!!**

I'm adding here some more code for further information...

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :set_locale

  before_filter :authenticate_customer!
  before_filter :authenticate_admin!

  # Set locale according to locale parameter.
  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end

  # Set actual locale value to be the default locale parameter.
  def default_url_options(options={})
    { locale: I18n.locale }
  end

  # Configure permitted parameters for devise.
  protected

  def devise_parameter_sanitizer
    if resource_class == Customer
      Customer::ParameterSanitizer.new(Customer, :customer, params)
    else
      super # Use the default one
    end
  end
end
```

**welcome_controller.rb** (my one and only controller for now)

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_action :authenticate_customer!
  skip_before_action :authenticate_admin!

  before_filter :require_admin_not_signed_in
  before_filter :require_customer_not_signed_in

  def home
  end

  private

  # Add filter to skip home page if customer is already signed in.
  def require_customer_not_signed_in
    unless not customer_signed_in?
      redirect_to member_dashboard_path
    end
  end

  # Add filter to skip home page if admin is already signed in.
  def require_admin_not_signed_in
    unless not admin_signed_in?
      redirect_to admin_dashboard_path
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED!!!**

In my models I was adding a fix for a session serializing problem in **Devise**. This fix was causing the issue. This is the fix I'm talking about:

```
.
.
.
# Devise serializing problem fix.
  class << self
    def serialize_from_session(key,salt)
      record = to_adapter.get(key[0].to_param)
      record if record && record.authenticatable_salt == salt
    end
  end
.
.
.
```

I've changed that to this:

```
.
.
.
# Devise serializing problem fix.
  class << self
    def serialize_from_session(key, salt)
      record = to_adapter.get(key[0]["$oid"])
      record if record && record.authenticatable_salt == salt
    end
  end
.
.
.
```

And now it all works!.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Your settings look correct and the issue isn't in your modules else sign in etc would not be working.

I would personally go through the following:

1. Ensure before_filter :authenticate_< scope >! is on your ApplicationController (swap out scope for user etc).  Then use a skip_before_filter on the controllers you dont want protected
2. Ensure you are not attempting to access current_user etc from a controller action that is skipping the authenticate_user filter
3. All correct?  Try patching your own SessionController if you havnt already ie. Devise::SessionsController and manually overwrite methods and test with trial and error.

Would i be able to see your Application and session controllers?

Comment: I'll try option 1 you're mentioning and let you know!. Thanks!. If it doesn't work I'll post my application controller. Best,

Comment: Allan, option 1 didn't work for me. I haven't patched my own SessionController yet since I'm not pretty sure how to do it right. I'll make an update to the question so you can take a look at my application controller. Also I'm adding the one and only controller (besides ApplicationController) I'm using for now since I'm just starting to build my app.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar problem with Devise and Mongoid.

I came to another solution, which also improves the session object by keeping it simple (it will store a string instead of BSON::Object)[1]

```
class User
  # ...
  # Serialize string instead of BSON
  def self.serialize_into_session(record)
    [record.to_key.map(&:to_s), record.authenticatable_salt]
  end

  # Serialize string instead of BSON
  def self.serialize_into_cookie(record)
    [record.to_key.map(&:to_s), record.rememberable_value]
  end
  # ...
end
```

Be aware of "serialize into cookie" because it is as important as serialize_into_session if you are using the remember me feature

[1] https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/issues/405#issue-10811843